# Which classifiers provide weight vector?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, multilabel-classification

What machine learning classifiers exists which provide after the learning phase a weight vector? I know about SVM, logistic regression, perceptron and LDA. Are there more?

My goal is to use these weight vector to draw an importance map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually any [linear classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Linear_classifier) has such a property by design.

As I understand, what you want to do is something like feature selection without cut-off of least useful ones.

See [the paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.85.2088&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> Mladenić, D., Brank, J., Grobelnik, M., & Milic-Frayling, N. (2004,
>   July). Feature selection using linear classifier weights: interaction
>   with classification models. In Proceedings of the 27th annual
>   international ACM SIGIR conference on Research and development in
>   information retrieval (pp. 234-241). ACM.

authors compare several methods for feature selection including usage of SVM weights and find the last to be the best.